# Prolog program with fixed queries

Tags: prolog, ontology

I'm trying to make some queries on my ontology using prolog (with sem_web library).

I've already tested queries launching swi-prolog, but what I would do is to write a .pl file with fixed queries and then launching .sh to obtain results. Is it possible?

I would get results in order to save them, like in a txt.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. See example below. (It is from Windows command line, but you should get good idea how to do this in Linux environment.)

Contents of `hello_world.pl`:

```
hello_world(X) :-
    print('Hello'), print(X), print('!'), nl.
```

Command line (or potential content of batch/shell script):

```
swipl -s hello_world.pl -g "hello_world('World'),halt" --quiet > output.txt
```

Contents of `output.txt`:

```
HelloWorld!
```